# editing the default title for directory views in apache with htaccess

Tags: css, apache, .htaccess

I'm trying to pretty up the default directory view in apache with an htaccess file. I've done pretty much everything I want to do, except change the default verbiage for the title. By default, it says something like:

```
"Index of [folder_name]"
```

and if I use this:

```
# SPECIFY HEADER FILE
HeaderName /apache/header.html
```

in htaccess, I can include my own header title, which I like because I can add CSS styling and whatnot, but I cannot make the title change with each folder I visit. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want `IndexOptions +SuppressHTMLPreamble`.

From the [Apache mod_autoindex docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_autoindex.html#headername):

> If the file specified by `HeaderName` contains the beginnings of an HTML document (`<html>`, `<head>`, etc.) then you will probably want to set `IndexOptions +SuppressHTMLPreamble`, so that these tags are not repeated.

Comment: Yeah I have that in place - that's just to get rid of the existing title and replace it with something static, not to preserve the dynamism of the default apache functionality I think. But thanks.

Comment: Oh I see what you are wanting. Sorry, my mistake. Anyways, I think noodl is right and javascript is the best option.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what I was after - http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/env.html

Enter this as the title for your h1 tags: `<!--#echo var="REQUEST_URI" -->` and save the header with a .shtml tag extension and your titles become dynamic. However, I still would like to be able to change the verbiage - get rid of the "Index of" and maybe have only the current directory show rather than the path to the directory.

Answer (score 1):

You could probably specify a HeaderName that points to a generated page (mod_includes, for example, or mod_php) and read the environment variables from there.

Alternatively, you could serve up some javascript that reads the current url and sets the title as appropriate.

mod_dir can't do this on its own.

Comment: Thanks - I'm pretty clueless when it comes to that unfortunately, but thanks for the help.